# WSO2 BAM Cluster

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, wso2, wso2-bam

I´m configuring a WSO2 BAM Cluster with external Cassandra and Hadoop Cluster following the indications in the [CLUSTER420](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+Data+Analyzer+Cluster+in+BAM+2.5.0) documentation for WSO2 BAM 2.5.0 and in section 14 I found this:

Change the following properties in the /repository/conf/advanced/hive-site.xml file.

Change the below properties if you are using the incremental data processing and notification task features.

```
<property>
    <name>hive.incremental.processing.intermediate.results.cassandra.hosts</name>
    <value>localhost:9160</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.incremental.processing.intermediate.results.cassandra.userName</name>
    <value>admin</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.incremental.processing.intermediate.results.cassandra.password</name>
    <value>admin</value>
</property>
<!-- Credentials for WSO2BAM_UTILS_KS -->
<property>
    <name>notification.task.receiver.username</name>
    <value>admin</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>notification.task.receiver.password</name>
    <value>admin</value>
</property>
```

My questions:

1. In my cassandra cluster I had 3 nodes, so what I need to put in "hive.incremental.processing.intermediate.results.cassandra.hosts" property value?
2. In the "cassandra.userName" and "cassandra.password" I put admin and admin or my cassandra cluster credentials?
3. In the credentials for WSO2BAM_UTILS_KS I put admin and admin or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. List all hostnames as comma separated list
2. provide cassendra cluster credentials
3. It is not necessary to put credentials for WSO2_BAM_UTIL_KS. Rather,  mention all credentials correctly on $BAM_HOME/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasource.xml